# Populating textboxes using LINQ2SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

In my web forms, I have text boxes and one radiolist which I need to populate through a LINQ2SQL query. So far I coded this query to fetch particular records which is going to be populated into the DB.

```
 using (dbTestDataContext db = new dbTestDataContext())
        {
            var query = from r in db.Table1
                        where r.Code == getCode
                        select new
                        {
                            //Account Info
                            r.Name,
                            r.Num,
                            r.AcctNum,
                            r.CorpAcct, //Bool


                        };
        };
```

Now I know that the record which this query is going to be fetching is gonna be only 1 unique record. I want to show the record in these textboxes and select that radio button:

> tbName
>    tbNum
>    tbAcctNum
>    rbtnCorpAcct

How should I do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as others have answered with addition of radio button:

```
tbName.Text = query.Name;
tbNum.Text = query.Num;
tbAcctNum.Text = query.AcctNum;

if(query.CorpAcct)
    rbtn.SelectedValue = "Yes"; \\Where "Yes" is one of the radio button values
else
    rbtn.SelectedValue = "No";

\\Could also use SelectedIndex, rbtn.SelectedIndex = 0 or 1
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. There is no property defined for radiobuttonlist as rbtn.Checked.

Comment: Thought it was just a RadioButton. For a list you'll have to select the value of the "Yes" radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Very simply:

```
 using (dbTestDataContext db = new dbTestDataContext())
        {
            var query = (from r in db.Table1
                        where r.Code == getCode
                        select new
                        {
                            //Account Info
                            r.Name,
                            r.Num,
                            r.AcctNum,
                            r.CorpAcct, //Bool


                        }).FirstOrDefault();

             if (query != null)
             {
                tbName.Text = query.Name;
                tbNum.Text = query.Num;
                //and so on
                rbl.SelectedValue = query.SomeValue;
             }
        };
```

Comment: What about the Radiobuttonlist ?

Comment: Updated above, set the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
using (dbTestDataContext db = new dbTestDataContext())
{
    var query = 
    (
        from r in db.Table1
        where r.Code == getCode
        select new
        {
            //Account Info
            r.Name,
            r.Num,
            r.AcctNum,
            r.CorpAcct, //Bool
        }
    ).FirstOrDefault();

    tbName.Text = query.Name;

    ....

};
```

Comment: What about the radio button lists?

Comment: Oops! My fault...I removed it.

Comment: @klm9971: RadioButtonList.Items[ItemIndex].Selected = BooleanValue;

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is retrieve a single result from your query. As you have it written, you are returning an IQueryable object which is now stored in the variable "query"

To get a single object, do this

```
var myObject = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

Then you can access the individual properties of that object and assign them like this

`tbName.Text = myObject.Name`