# Multiple textbox insert into to sql table in separate rows using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Inserting values of text boxes into specific columns of a single row of a sql table usign LINQ is not a big deal but how to insert content of each textbox in new row, for example if we have 5 text boxes so it should create 5 new rows in sql table. Below is how I insert text boxes into different columns of a single row :

```
Table Name: tblModulRelayConfig 

index   fltCe  fltUT1  fltUT2  fltUT3  fltUT4  fltUT5  fltUT6

1       75     Text1   Text2   Text3   Text4   Text5   Text6
2       76     Text1   Text2   Text3   Text4   Text5   Text6


       using (myDataContext mydc= new myDataContext())
           {
           tblModulRelayConfig tblModuler = (from CE in mydc.tblCEs
                                             where CE.fltCE == 75
                                             select CE).FirstOrDefault();
           if(tblModuler != null)//in order to update table
             {
                    nyModul.fltUT1 = TextBox1.Text;
                    nyModul.fltUT2 = TextBox2.Text;
                    nyModul.fltUT3 = TextBox3.Text;
                    nyModul.fltUT4 = TextBox4.Text;
                    nyModul.fltUT5 = TextBox5.Text;
                    nyModul.fltUT6 = TextBox6.Text;
             }
             else // if it does no exist already 
             {
                    tblModulRelayConfig nyModul = new tblModulRelayConfig();
                    nyModul.fltUT1 = TextBox1.Text;
                    nyModul.fltUT2 = TextBox2.Text;
                    nyModul.fltUT3 = TextBox3.Text;
                    nyModul.fltUT4 = TextBox4.Text;
                    nyModul.fltUT5 = TextBox5.Text;
                    nyModul.fltUT6 = TextBox6.Text;

                    mydc.tblModulRelayConfigs.InsertOnSubmit(nyModul);

                    mydc.SubmitChanges();
            }
         }
```

But how to create a table as follow, I mean instead of inserting text boxe values in single line, I want to insert data of each text boxe in new rows in single button click:

```
tblModulRelayConfig 

index   fltCe  fltUTNr  fltUT  

1       75     1        Text1   
2       75     2        Text2  
3       75     3        Text3  
4       75     4        Text4  
5       75     5        Text5  
6       75     6        Text6
```

I tried the following code but without break in loop it only add the last textboxe data into table and with break it only add the first textboxe value.
The code I try to use is from below link :
[Show Linq-to-SQL table rows in separate text boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014307/show-linqto-sql-table-rows-in-separate-text-boxes)

```
  var textbox = GetAll(this, typeof(TextBox));
                tblModulRelayConfig nyKanal = new tblModulRelayConfig ();
                foreach (Control c in textbox)
                {
                    textNr++;
                    if (c is TextBox)
                    {
                        var tx = ((TextBox)c);
                        nyKanal.fltUTNr = textNr;
                        nyKanal.fltUT=tx.Text;
                        sls.tblModulRelayConfig .InsertOnSubmit(nyKanal);
                        sls.SubmitChanges();
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this solution. I've replaced the `fltUTNr` with `fltUTName` that contains the name of the textboxes. In this way you have a stronger binding with your ui:

```
index   fltCe  fltUTName  fltUT  

1       75     TexBox1    Text1   
2       75     TexBox2    Text2  
3       75     TexBox3    Text3  
4       75     TexBox4    Text4  
5       75     TexBox5    Text5  
6       75     TexBox6    Text6


int fltCE_item = 75;

using (myDataContext mydc= new myDataContext()){

   List<tblModulRelayConfig> tblModuler = (
             from CE in mydc.tblCEs 
             where CE.fltCE == fltCE_item 
             select CE
   );

   foreach(TextBox tx in GetAll(this, typeof(TextBox)){

      if(tblModuler.Count > 0){ //update table
         foreach(var CE in tblModuler)
            if(CE.fltUTName.Equals(tx.Name))
               CE.fltUT = tx.Text;

      }else{ //insert: index should be autoseeded into the db;

        tblModulRelayConfig nyModul = new tblModulRelayConfig();
        nyModul.fltCe = fltCE_item;
        nyModul.fltUTName = tx.Name; 
        nyModul.fltUT = tx.Text; 

        mydc.tblModulRelayConfigs.InsertOnSubmit(nyModul);
      }
   }
   mydc.SubmitChanges();
}
```